# Export generated class files and resources equivalent command line command

Tags: java, jar

I'am working on a python script , which involves few steps of creating a jar file.
However when i run the following lines of code i get the jar file created, having .java files and not .class files .

```
subprocess.call(['jar', 'cvf', 'process.jar','C:/my data/temp/process/src'])
```

Is there any way to get the jar file created with .class files similar to Export generated class files and resources checkbox in export jar dialog in eclipse .

Thanks

Comment: Does your script compile the `.java` files anywhere?

Comment: Does the same command run from command line create a jar with class files? How is the compiler invoked in this command, from your point of view?

Comment: @durron597 The script does not compile . java files , but the requirement is to automate a jar file creation process which is currently done by eclipse .So if i try to do generate the jar file i from eclipse i get .class file in jar instead of java files if i click on that checkbox . i want to mimic that same functionality using python .

Comment: If you're going to replace the steps that Eclipse does, don't you think it would be important to `javac` the latest version of all the files first?

Comment: @durron597 Yes , i agree with you . But i was wondering if there was any way to see what commands eclipse runs in console while generating jar file , then i could have ran those same commands in my code .

Comment: @user106351 If your question is about what eclipse does (as opposed to what's needed to create a .jar file), perhaps you should edit your question to say that?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help , i wrote an ant script and the issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Make sure where is your `*.class` files located, I assume it is in **bin** directory or something:

```
subprocess.call(['jar', 'cvf', 'process.jar','C:/my data/temp/process/bin'])
```